# Name of audio device by ID(waveout c++)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, waveout

I need to discover name of audio device by ID. I use WaveOut functions. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example on how to enumerate waveIn and waveOut devices on your system:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2012/03/13/sample-how-to-enumerate-wavein-and-waveout-devices-on-your-system.aspx

So, you can just compare dev id you need and get name of the device.